# Python program that draws the Mandelbrot set fractal

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy

I wrote a Python program that draws the Mandelbrot set fractal. However, the program is very slow. I would appreciate any feedback on the program, but I would especially appreciate feedback on how to improve the performance of my program.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np

def FractalFunc(x, c):
    return (x * x) + c

def IterateFractal(c, iterateMax=100):
    z = 0
    last = np.nan
    for i in range(iterateMax):
        # c = FractalFunc(c, (.05+.5j)) # in case I want to create the Julia set
        z = FractalFunc(z,c)
        # if (np.abs(c) > 2):
        if (np.abs(z) > 2):
            last = i
            break
    return last

def QuickFractal(width=200, height=200, amin=-1.5, amax=1.5, bmin=-1.5, bmax=1.5, 
            iterateMax=100, filename="blah.png"):
    (w, h, iMax, iterationValues, histogram) = Fractal(width, height, amin, amax, bmin, bmax, iterateMax)
    iFractal = DrawFractal(w, h, iMax, iterationValues, histogram)
    iFractal.show()
    iFractal.save(filename)    

def ShowFractal(frac, filename="test.png"):
    (w, h, iMax, iterationValues, histogram) = frac
    iFractal = DrawFractal(w, h, iMax, iterationValues, histogram)
    iFractal.show()
    iFractal.save(filename)

def Fractal(width=200, height=200, amin=-1.5, amax=1.5, bmin=-1.5, bmax=1.5, 
            iterateMax=100):
    aStep = (amax - amin) / (width)
    bStep = (bmax - bmin) / (height)
    """compute iteration values"""
    iterationValues = np.zeros((width, height))
    histogram = np.zeros(iterateMax)
    a = amin
    for x in range(width):
        b = bmin
        for y in range(height):
            c = np.complex(a,b)
            i = IterateFractal(c, iterateMax)
            iterationValues[x][y] = i
            if not(np.isnan(i)):
                histogram[i] = histogram[i] + 1
            b = b + bStep
        a = a + aStep
    return (width, height, iterateMax, iterationValues, histogram)

def DrawFractal(width, height, iterateMax, iterationValues, histogram):
    hue = np.zeros(iterateMax)
    hue[0] = histogram[0] / sum(histogram)
    image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
    for i in range(1, iterateMax):
        hue[i] = hue[i-1] + (histogram[i] / sum(histogram))
    """second pass to draw the values"""
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            i_count = iterationValues[x,y]
            colorPixel = FractalColor(i_count, iterateMax, hue)
            image.putpixel((x,y), colorPixel)
    return image

def FractalColor(iterate, maxIt, hues):
    if np.isnan(iterate):
        return (0,0,0)
    else:
        grad_point_1 = np.array((0, 0, 255))
        grad_point_2 = np.array((255, 255, 255))
        grad_point_3 = np.array((0, 0, 255))
        hue_mod = (iterate % 100) / 100
        if (0 <= hue_mod < (.5)):
            delta = grad_point_2 - grad_point_1
            start = grad_point_1
        if ((.5) <= hue_mod < (1)):
            delta = grad_point_3 - grad_point_2
            start = grad_point_2
        scalar = ((hue_mod * 100) % (100 / 2))/30
        arr = np.floor(start + np.dot(scalar, delta))
        return tuple(arr.astype(int))
```

Example output:

[image: Mandelbrot set]

Comment: You can get some optimisations from [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Optimizations)

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key thing to remember when working with numerical code is that the CPython interpreter is pretty slow (it trades speed for flexibility) and so you must avoid running in the interpreter whenever possible. Instead of iterating in slow Python bytecode using `for x in ...`, operate on whole arrays by calling the appropriate NumPy function or method, which dispatches to fast compiled code operating on fixed-size numbers.

So to speed up `Fractal` we must turn it inside out — instead of operating on one pixel at a time, we must operate on the whole array at once.

1. Let's start out by measuring the performance of the implementation in the post:

   ```
   >>> from timeit import timeit
   >>> timeit(Fractal, number=1)
   1.4722420040052384
   ```
2. The constants \$c\$ are computed one at a time:

   ```
   a = amin
   for x in range(width):
       b = bmin
       for y in range(height):
           c = np.complex(a,b)
           # ...
           b = b + bStep
       a = a + aStep
   ```

   Instead, compute a whole array of constants \$c\$ using [`numpy.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) and [`numpy.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

   ```
   a, b = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(amin, amax, width),
                      np.linspace(bmin, bmax, height), sparse=True)
   c = a + 1j * b
   ```
3. The `IterateFractal` function operates on the \$z\$ value for a single pixel at a time. Instead, we should operate on a whole array of \$z\$ values:

   ```
   z = np.zeros_like(c)
   iterations = np.zeros_like(c, dtype=int)
   for i in range(1, iterateMax + 1):
       z = z ** 2 + c
       iterations[abs(z) <= 2] = i
   ```

   Note that in this implementation, points that never escape from the set have `iterations` equal to `iterateMax` (rather than NaN as in the post). This requires a corresponding change to `FractalColor`:

   ```
   def FractalColor(iterate, maxIt, hues):
       if iterate >= maxIt:
           return (0,0,0)
       else:
           # ...
   ```
4. Instead of computing `histogram` one pixel at a time, use [`numpy.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

   ```
   histogram = np.bincount(iterations.flatten())
   ```
5. This results in the revised code:

   ```
   def Fractal2(width=200, height=200, amin=-1.5, amax=1.5, bmin=-1.5,
                bmax=1.5, iterateMax=100):
       a, b = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(amin, amax, width),
                          np.linspace(bmin, bmax, height), sparse=True)
       c = a + 1j * b
       z = np.zeros_like(c)
       iterations = np.zeros_like(c, dtype=int)
       for i in range(1, iterateMax + 1):
           z = z ** 2 + c
           iterations[abs(z) <= 2] = i
       histogram = np.bincount(iterations.flatten())
       return width, height, iterateMax, iterations.T, histogram
   ```

   Note the `iterations.T` at the end there: the `.T` property is a shorthand for [`numpy.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html). This is needed because NumPy prefers *row-major* ordering where a 2-dimensional array is indexed by *row*, *column*, but `DrawFractal` is using *column-major* ordering where an image is indexed by *x*, *y*.  See the Numpy documentation on "[Multidimensional Array Indexing Order Issues](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html#multidimensional-array-indexing-order-issues)". If you updated `DrawFractal` to use row-major indexing then you would avoid the need for this transpose.

   This is about 40 times as fast as the original code:

   ```
   >>> timeit(Fractal2, number=1)
   0.03542686498258263
   ```
6. There are a couple of problems with the whole-array approach. First, it wastes work: once a \$z\$ value has escaped the set, we don't need to keep iterating it. Second, by continuing to iterate the \$z\$ value, we might find that it overflows the range of floating-point numbers, resulting in unwanted overflow warnings.

   So what we can do is to keep track of the indexes of the pixels that have not yet escaped the set, and only operate on the corresponding values of \$z\$:

   ```
   def Fractal3(width=200, height=200, amin=-1.5, amax=1.5, bmin=-1.5, bmax=1.5, 
               iterateMax=100):
       a, b = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(amin, amax, width),
                          np.linspace(bmin, bmax, height), sparse=True)
       c = (a + 1j * b).flatten()
       z = np.zeros_like(c)
       ix = np.arange(len(c)) # Indexes of pixels that have not escaped.
       iterations = np.empty_like(ix)
       for i in range(iterateMax):
           zix = z[ix] = z[ix] ** 2 + c[ix]
           escaped = abs(zix) > 2
           iterations[ix[escaped]] = i
           ix = ix[~escaped]
       iterations[ix] = iterateMax
       histogram = np.bincount(iterations)
       iterations = iterations.reshape((height, width))
       return width, height, iterateMax, iterations.T, histogram
   ```

   Note that when operating on a set of indexes like this, it's most convenient to work with a *flattened* array, so that we only need one array of indexes. (If we used a two-dimensional array, we'd need to maintain two arrays of indexes `ix` and `iy`.) So we call [`numpy.flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatten.html) at the start to flatten the array to a single dimension, and [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) at the end to restore it to two dimensions.

   This is about 70 times as fast as the original code:

   ```
   >>> timeit(Fractal3, number=1)
   0.02115203905850649
   ```
7. Now that you've seen how to make `Fractal` operate on the whole array (rather than one pixel at a time), you should be able to do the same for `DrawFractal`. (Hint: instead of calling [`Image.putpixel`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putpixel) for each pixel, call [`Image.putdata`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putdata) once.)

Comment: So I finally got around to implementing all of these suggestions. I do have one question: can Image.putdata accept anything other than a one-dimensional array of tuples.

Comment: Right now I'm using the code `for i in range(len(hues)):  hues[i] = (red[i], green[i], blue[i])` (red, green, and blue are 2d numpy arrays, hues is a 1d python list), but I'm not sure if it's slowing down the code significantly

Comment: I went ahead and posted my updated version of the code: I would love it if you took a look. I still haven't implemented point six: I plan to once I spend some more time making sure I understand all of your advice. Thank you for the answer, by the way, it really improved my understanding of python and numpy.